# Partnership enrolling in Apple Developer Program

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I'm enrolled in my company's apple developer program, but am looking to develop apps outside of work.

My partner and I plan to develop apps together and publish them to the Apple App Store, but by the looks of things, we can only do this if we are registered as a business and have business licenses etc.  As this is just a small, joint venture, we have not really set ourselves up as a business.

Is there any way around this? I can enroll as an individual, but then my partner would also need to enroll, and we would only be able to publish under one of our names.